# Azure Search - regex search

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to configure Azure Search to find some strings that have special characters, for example
ABC*DEF

When I look for a the full term using `"ABC*DEF"`, it works perfectly.

The problem comes if I want to use a regex term:

- When I use a partial term, like `/(.*)ABC(.*)/`, the result has no problem
- When I use a partial term, like `/(.*)DEF(.*)/`, the result has no problem
- But when I try to look for something like `/(.*)C\*D(.*)/`, the result is empty.

I am using a standard analyzer. I tried also the keyword analyzer but that way the regex search doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have the trailing / at the end. Another possibility could be having to escape the backslash. Have you tried /(.*)C\\\*D(.*)/ ? In some languages there is a level of parsing that takes place before the regex engine gets its turn. Afraid I don't have any direct experience with Azure Search.

Comment: Thank you, the missing trailing / was a typo. Yes, I also tried that and still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to create a regex expression that matches ABC*DEF using the standard analyzer.

If you run `"ABC\*DEF"` through the [analyzer api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) using "standard" analyzer, you will see that `ABC*DEF` gets divided into 2 tokens at indexing time -> `"ABC"` and `"DEF"`. Regex expression are not analyzed, however, they need to match a token that exist in the index.

Since `ABC\*DEF` does not exist in the index (only "ABC" and "DEF" exist), you won't be able to find it using the expression you are searching for.

Using the "keyword" analyzer will keep the whole field as a single token, so if the field "only" contained the expression `ABC\*DEF`, then the regex expression would work on it, however, if `ABC\*DEF` is part of a larger paragraph of text, then that's probably not what you want to use.

Your best bet is to create a [custom analyzer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/) that tokenizes your text in the way that preserves the special characters that are relevant to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I created a custom analyzer and now I have the token `ABC*DEF` in place, but still when I use the regex `/(.*)ABC\*DEF(.*)/` or `/(.*)ABC*DEF(.*)/` it does not return any match. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for special chars, why don't you discard normal chars?

```
[^\w]
```